# AWS EBS extra volume gets attached to EC2 instances launched when creating ECS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-ami, amazon-ebs

When I create an ECS cluster with EC2 instances, they get created with the 22gb ebs storage attached as block device(that I have defined as the storage) and the root device is attached with another 30gb storage automatically (created from a public snapshot `snap-069c037282d89ccd8`).

Is this the correct behavior for ECS container instances? Does it always attach the other 30gb as well for every instances?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct behavior for ECS container instances? Does it always attach the other 30gb as well for every instances?

This is correct and you can change it, see the [ECS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-ami-storage-config.html) for details.

Comment: But according to the docs, it should be launched with an 8gb volume attached at `/dev/xvda` and 22gb as `/dev/xvdcz`. But instead I have 30gb attached as `/dev/xvda`. The 22gb is fine, it's attached as `/dev/xvdcz`